# Create a dendrogram

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this

| SELF | OTHER |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 6 |
| 8 | 6 |
| 8 | 6 |

The self represent the 8 football players and the other represents with which of this 8 football  players one  is befriended. I one to evaluate how similar two football players have a friendship circle, also share same people as friends. And  then I would like to do a clustering

This is what I did so far, but got error message

```
footballplayers  <- read.csv("footballplayer.csv", header = TRUE)
footballplayers_e <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(footballplayers),directed = TRUE)
similarities <- as.dist(1 - cor(footballplayers_e), upper = TRUE) 
footballplayersdend<-hclust(similarities)
plot(footballplayersdend)
```

But it doesn't work.

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : as.sociomatrix.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, network, or list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to get an adjacency matrix from an edge list is by using `Matrix::sparseMatrix`

```r
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(~SELF, ~OTHER,
              1,    3,
              1,    4,
              1,    5,
              2,    6,
              2,    1,
              2,    5,
              3,    5,
              3,    4,
              3,    2,
              4,    8,
              4,    7,
              4,    5,
              5,    1,
              5,    2,
              5,    3,
              6,    7,
              6,    8,
              6,    5,
              7,    5,
              7,    2,
              7,    3,
              8,    6,
              8,    6,
              8,    6)
with(df, Matrix::sparseMatrix(SELF, OTHER, symmetric = TRUE))

##> 8 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"
##>                     
##> [1,] . . | | | . . .
##> [2,] . . . . | | . .
##> [3,] | . . | | . . .
##> [4,] | . | . | . | |
##> [5,] | | | | . . . .
##> [6,] . | . . . . | |
##> [7,] . . . | . | . .
##> [8,] . . . | . | . .
```

Then we can apply `dist` and `hclust` e.g.:

```
with(df, Matrix::sparseMatrix(SELF, OTHER, symmetric = TRUE)) |>
    dist("binary") |>
    hclust() |>
    plot()
```

[image]